# Change month in DatePickerDialog listener Android Studio

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to implement a datePickerDialog in android studio , and I want to know when the user scrolls between months or presses on one of the arrows to go from one month to another
?
Is there anyway I can listen for users pressing month pagination ? or is there any library that allows me to ?

Answer (score 0):

In the [DatePikerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#onDateChanged(android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int)) you can see in the documentation there is a method given which is called when any view is clicked onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which).

You can use this method to know when the user clicks the month arrow and handle the logic there.